# Best practice for triggering events on calling page from an ajax page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have a page that lists a bunch of files. This page can be accessed directly via a URL or it can be loaded in a modal dialog via ajax from a different page.

If the files page is loaded via ajax, I would like to allow the user to click the name of the file and trigger an action in the page which loaded the files page. For example, there is an article edit page. This page contains an "attach a file" button. When the user clicks the button, the files page is loaded in a modal dialog and when a filename is clicked, the id of the file is inserted into the article form and the dialog is closed. However there is also an event edit page with a similar button, but I would like to handle the filename-click event slightly differently on this page.

I'd like to handle these click events slightly differently depending on the calling page. At the moment I'm defining a handler function with global scope in the page containing the form to which files are being attached, then testing for that function in the the files-page when the filename is clicked and calling if it exists. It works but it feels a little hacky. Is there some kind of best practice for this sort of thing that I'm not aware of?

I'm using jQuery if this makes things easier in any way..

Comment: I think you need to define what you're calling the "ajax" page and the "calling page" and "different locations".

Comment: updated - hope this is a little clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at [jQuery Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

When a Ajax page is loaded it's not processed by the DOM in the same way the main page was loaded, therefore using live will attach the event on all current event emitters as well as the future ones such as dynamic Ajax content

Within your Ajax model

```
<div>
    ...
    <a href="#" id="ajax_click_event">Add to main page</a>
    ...
</div>
```

and within your static page (the one originally loaded)

```
$("#ajax_click_event").live('click',function(){
    //Work wit the value of the form within the ajax div.
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of relying on a global handler function as the interface between pages, you could rely on custom events instead:

**"calling page":**

```
$(document).bind("fileClicked", function(event, fileName) {
    alert(fileName);
});
```

**"page loaded via ajax":**

```
$(".file").click(function() {
    $(document).trigger("fileClicked", [$(this).text()]);
});
```

Comment: are these fired with ajax content though, would you not have to use `$('entity').live('name',callback)`

Comment: @RobertPitt `live` isn't necessary. The click events are attached on the page which is loaded via ajax, not the calling page.